# Navegar a rutas hijas BottomNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una pequeña aplicación en flutter que implementa un bottomNavigationBar que manejo con provider para el cambio entre pantallas.

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: _HomePageBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigatonBar(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomePageBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const _HomePageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final uiProvider = Provider.of<UiProvider>(context);

    final currentIndex = uiProvider.selectedMenuOpt;

    switch (currentIndex) {
      case 0:
        return const Option1Screen();

      case 1:
        return const Option2Screen();


      default:
        return const Option1Screen();
    }
  }
```

Esta es mi OptionScreen1

```
    class Option1Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Option1Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 40),
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed('page_child')
            }, child: Text('go page child'))

          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Option1]

Necesito que al presionar el botón navegue a otra pantalla(Navigator.pushNamed('page_child')) que siempre aparezca el BottomNavigationBar y siempre seleccionada la primera opción.
Al hacerlo con el actual código muestra la pagina 'page_child' pero no aparece el BottomNavigationBar.
También puede darse el caso que dentro de la pantalla page_child tenga otro botón que tenga que navegar a otra pagina que seria hija de la pagina page_child y asi podria tener varias rutas sub-hijas necesitaria que en todas muestre el BottomNavigationBar siempre seleccionada la opcion 1.

No se si existe algo como hijas rutas que se pueden ir anidando así como se hace con framework web como vue

Estas son mis rutas

```
 'home': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
'option1': (context) => const Option1Screen(),
'option2': (context) => const Option2Screen(),
'page_child': (context) => const PageChildScreen(),
'other_child': (context) => const PageOtherChildScreen(),
```

Comment: Podrías usar un Navigator anidado. No te pongo ejemplo, porque nunca lo he usado, pero creo que podría ser una buena solución

Comment: buscare información al respecto

Comment: Una cosilla, aunque lo que pides, de cierta manera, lo he visto en alguna que otra app, realmente no es el comportamiento que debiera tener un BottomNavigation. Por lo que quizás, te recomendaría usar un Drawer https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer, que está más pensado para mostrarse en cualquier pantalla. El Bottom debería usarse solo para pantallas de primer nivel, las más importantes y se haces push de otra cosa, debería taparse. No sé si te sirva de algo, pero podría ahorrarte unos cuantos dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haría yo es crear `Widgets` o `Clases` para los hijos de la clase padre, en este caso la clase padre sería `Option1Screen`, en tal caso, modificariamos un poquito esta clase, y quedaría algo así:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Option1Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Option1Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Option1Screen> createState() => _Option1ScreenState();
}

class _Option1ScreenState extends State<Option1Screen> {
  String ruta = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return seleccionPantalla();
  }

  Widget seleccionPantalla() {
    //PARA VALIDAR QUE PANTALLA SE VA A MOSTRAR DEPENDIENDO LA ACCIÓN
    switch (ruta) {
      case "pagina2":
        return paginaSecundaria();
      case "pagina3":
        return terceraPagina();
      default:
        return paginaPrincipal();
    }
  }

  //EL PRIMER WIDGET QUE TE SE VA A MOSTRAR
  Widget paginaPrincipal() => ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 40),
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Quitamos el navigator, porque ya no vamos a ir a otra página, si no que nos quedaremos en la misma
                      setState(() {
                        ruta = "pagina2";
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('go page child')),
                //Un ejemplo más
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        ruta = "pagina3";
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('go page child'))
              ],
            )
          ]);

  //LO QUE SE IBA A MOSTRAR EN PANTALLA CUANDO IBAS A NAVEGAR, SE MOSTRARÁ EN ESTE WIDGET
  Widget paginaSecundaria() => const Center(
        child: Text("Página secundaria"),
      );

  //ESTE ES OTRO EJEMPLO EN CASO QUE LA CLASE PADRE TENGA MAS BOTONES
  Widget terceraPagina() => const Center(
        child: Text("Tercera página"),
      );
}
```

Esa es una de las soluciones, puedes separar el código para que tu clase se vea limpia, espero y mi respuesta te haya servido

Comment: Con esta solución  si tengo varias paginas hijas y estoy  en la pagina hija 4 y quiero regresar a la pagina hija 3(como se hace cuando navegas con rutas y agregas un appBar) se podrá hacer?

Comment: No lo he intentado la verdad, pero para poder regresar, puedes crear un IconButton por página y en el onPressed le dices que te regrese en la última que estabas, ejemplo, supongamos que la ultima era la pagina cuatro, y ahora pulsaste un botón que te presentó la página 5, entonces en la propiedad onPressed le pones setState(() => ruta = "pagina4" ); y así con cada una de las páginas

Comment: Probé tu solución y funciona pero que pasa si en la pagina hija 1 que es hija de la opcion1 del tab  tengo otro botón que necesito que navegue a otra pagina que seria hija de la pagina 1 y así podría tener mas sub hijas.

Comment: Aplica la misma metodología, pero no se que tan recomendable sería tener hijas, hijas de las hijas, hijas de las hijas de las hijas en una sola pantalla, la otra solución sería crear un bottomNavigationBar global, para las páginas que la necesiten, pero al momento de cambiar de página vas a ver la transición de la página completa y lo que asumo que quieres hacer, es que el bottomNavigationBar se quede estático

Comment: Lo que no me gusta de aplicar lo mismo es que veo mucha duplicidad de código por cada ruta sub hija, el diseño de una app que tengo que hacer tiene ese funcionalidad que pueden haber hasta 4 sub rutas.

Comment: Encontre algo que te puede servir, chequea este link https://techblog.geekyants.com/nested-navigation-in-flutter-navigator-widget